# what is purpose in must nested in filter elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

what's difference between the following es filter query？
1. filter context for multi query conditions:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            { "term":  { "status": "published" }}, 
            { "range": { "publish_date": { "gte": "2015-01-01" }}} 
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

2. must in filter context:

```
    {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            { "term":  { "status": "published" }}, 
                            { "range": { "publish_date": { "gte": "2015-01-01" }}} 
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query is used in scenarios where you just want to filter using `AND` operator on different fields. By default if you write filter query in this way, it would be executed as `AND` operation.

The second query, in your case/scenario, does exactly as the first query (no difference, just two ways of doing same thing), ***however*** the reason we can "also" do that is to implement/cover more complex filter use-cases that uses many different `AND` and `OR` combinations.

Note that in Elasticsearch **AND** is represented by `must` while **OR** is represented by `should` clauses.

Let's say I would want to filter a scenario like I want all documents having

- **sales from department 101** or
- **sales from department 101B along with price > 150**.

You probably would have to end up writing query in the below way:

```
POST sometestindex/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":[  
            {  
               "bool":{  
                  "should":[  
                     {  
                        "term":{  
                           "dept.keyword":"101"
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "bool":{  
                           "must":[  
                              {  
                                 "term":{  
                                    "dept.keyword":"101B"
                                 }
                              },
                              {  
                                 "range":{  
                                    "price":{  
                                       "gte":150
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ],
                  "minimum_should_match": 1
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

In short, for your scenario, first query is just a short-hand way of writing the second-query, however if you have much more complex filter logic, then you need to leverage the Bool query inside your filter as you've mentioned in your second query, as I've mentioned in the sample example.

Hope that clarifies!

Comment: @WesleyHsiung I don't think so as both queries would be translated into similar execution.

Comment: @WesleyHsiung If you think the above answers you question, please feel free to upvote and accept the answer(by clicking the grey arrow next that's just under the upvote section). In that way people who come to check your question, would be aware that this answer has a solution. Thank you and feel free to ask any queries if you have one.